# Manipulating html page by .js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have successfully called the following JavaScript code to populate an image and description using parameters.
The image and description are in  tags and are called imagePlaceHolder and descriptionPlaceHolder. As I say, this works perfectly.

```
function changeImage(imgName,descriptiveText)
{
    image = document.getElementById('imagePlaceHolder');
    image.src = imgName;

    text = document.getElementById('descriptionPlaceHolder');
    PlaceHolder.innerHTML=descriptiveText;
}
```

What I now require is to place the javascript in its own file and call it from the HTML page using `<script src="xxxx.js"></script>`

The problem is that the object in the `<div>` is not recognized. I need to amend the line

```
document.getElementById('imagePlaceHolder');
```

to point to the HTML file containing object to manipulate.

Can anyone advise me of the correct syntax please?

Comment: Add the relevant html so we can see what you're trying to target or create a jsfiddle. It helps :) Also you're targeting a variable called "Placeholder". Is that supposed to be "text"?

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML file you need to link the javascript file in the header

E.g.

```
<head>
<script src="/scripts/yourjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

then do a onload function at the top of your javascript file

```
    window.onload = function(){
     changeImage("imgName", "descriptiveText");
    }

function changeImage(imgName,descriptiveText)
    {
        image = document.getElementById('imagePlaceHolder');
        image.src = imgName;

        text = document.getElementById('descriptionPlaceHolder');
        text.innerHTML=descriptiveText;
    }
```

any javascript using `document` should reference the html document